# Get Entries with a specified. Custom FieldType

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, custom-fieldtype

I have created a Custom FieldType with `AttributeType::Mixed` The field actually saves the a Custom Model I created. I'm trying to retrieve all the entries that have my custom model as the field. I'm trying to do this:

```
-
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
// testOrPanel is the name of my custom fieldtype.
$criteria->testOrPanel = ModelHelper::packageAttributeValue($test);
$entry = $criteria->first();
-
```

I know for a fact that the entry exists and has that value. and I have logged the ModelHelper result and it is exactly what the field has on the db, but it is not working.
it is resulting in blank.